# Javascript run match in an array with different values and says match is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a few objects in an array, they al have the same regex. 
The array looks like this: `var array = ["7711BZ","8877RG","7755LK"];`.
I have tried to loop through them, but then I get an error that match is not a function.

This is what I want to do. Loop through and array and then check in the match if they have this. Also I have tried this without an loop, because the array where my objects come from are from json data. So there is something in the array after something is clicked. That is why I have default objects right now.

```js
var string = [{"from": "7711KT", "to":"7711KZ"},{"from":" 7722LZ","to":"7722LG"}];
for(var j = 0; j < string.length; j++){
  var res = string[j].match(/\d{4}|[A-Z]{2}\b/g);
  var postcodeNumbers = res[0];
  var splitArray = res[1];
}
```

I have fixed this problem with `JSON.stringify(string[j]).match`

Comment: do you like to test the properties? wat result do you expect?

Comment: Don't you see that `string[j]` is not a string? I mean you have array of what? String or objects?

Comment: Your array does not look like that. In your code you have an array of objects, not an array of strings.

Comment: I have changed it to objects so they are objects

Comment: I want to split every object into two, so I can convert the letters to numbers.

Comment: Do you want to test your regex on `to` and `from` zipcode ?

Comment: Yes I want to test it

Comment: Your objects look like this: `{"from": "7711KT", "to":"7711KZ"}`. There seem to be two properties in each object, one named `from` and one named `to`, both of which have string values that match you regexp. Do you want to process both of those properties, or just one? Are both always present? Can there be other properties that you want to process? And what do you want to *do* with the properties once you've matched them?

Comment: There both always there

Comment: OK. What about the other questions I asked above?

Comment: Yes I want to process them all

Comment: OK, that's two answers. I asked four questions. Could you please answer the rest, too? I'd kind of *like* to help you fix your code, but it's hard to do that without knowing exactly what you want the code to do. (Also, I won't be notified about your comments here unless you [@ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) me. And you really should be editing the missing information I asked for into your question anyway.)

Comment: Also, one more question: what do you want the code to do if the input contains any properties that *don't* match your regexp? Should they be left alone, or should the code throw an error, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new array with objects and separate the numerical and letter part.

```js
function getParts(s) {
    return s.match(/\d{4}|[A-Z]{2}/g);
}

var array = [{ from: "7711KT", to: "7711KZ" }, { from: " 7722LZ", to: "7722LG" }],
    result = array.map(function (o) {
        return { from: getParts(o.from), to: getParts(o.to) };
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That `getParts()` function will produce quite... interesting results if the inputs *don't* match the expected `1234XY` pattern. Just try it on, say, `123XYZ` or `12345X` or `12X34Y`. It would be easy to make the function explicitly detect such invalid inputs and throw an error, or at least to process them in a way that does *not* silently throw away parts of the input.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, actually OP has not really state how the result should look like, butt assuming *"I want to split every object into two ..."* is meaning every property and then do something.